# How to set the user agent with Cache-Cow

Tags: c#, caching

When using cachecow to enable caching as HTTP-client, how can I set the user agent string? For now, I have the following as per the tutorial:

```
var client = ClientExtensions.CreateClient();
var data = client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
return data.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Doesn't setting it as normal (i.e. `DefaultRequestHeaders`) for `HttpClient` work?

Comment: Yes, indeed... I missed that